# Как центрировать слайды в Slick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Товарищи, кто знает легальные способы центрирования слайдов в slick?
Имеем слайдер навигации с превьюшками изображений. Ширина слайдов произвольная. Хочу, чтобы они располагались по центру, а по факту они с центра начинается.

```js
$("#main").slick({});

$("#slider").slick({    
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: false,
  asNavFor: "#main",
});
```

```css
#main {
  font-size: 32px;    
}

#slider {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.slide {     
   border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
   margin: 0 4px;
   text-align: center;
}

.middle {
   width: 50%;
   background: red;
   height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2wide</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</div>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2wide</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Пример]

На картинке выше пример. Первая - что есть, вторая то, что хотелось бы. Получается что в текущем виде слайды при переключении переходят с одной стороны центра на другую. А желаемое поведение. чтобы он начинали двигаться только когда начинаем листать те слайды, которые изначально не влезают в экран.

Comment: С какой целью вы используете centerMode? Чтобы стилизовать отдельно  центральный слайд?

Comment: @Get-Web ни с какой. нашел в документации хоть что-то похожее, но не то. включен `centerMode`или не не важно. важно получить нормальный вид слайдера.

Comment: Так нормальный слайдер будет без centerMode, centerMode полезен когда нужно выделить именно центральный слайд или реализовать что бы крайние слайдеры прятались к примеру на половину

Comment: @Get-Web не будет нормальный, будут все слайды слева,а не по центру. счас дополню пример, не совсем корректно сейчас, ибо нет `asNavFor`

Comment: вот готовый пример. https://codepen.io/get-web/pen/ZNrxvx при любом количестве слайдов они центрируются

Comment: @Get-Web центрируются, потому что фиксированной ширины слайды. `variableWidth: true` поставьте и перестанут. У вас контент предполагает равную ширину. у меня же превью изображений, слайд должен быть той же ширины, что и картинка.

Comment: раньше юзал jssor slider для галерей, но что-то он меня синтаксисом напрягал :) решил перейти на slick, но только проблем нашел. Все таки фотогалереи, наверное, более узкоспециализированное решение, чем просто слайдер.

Comment: В таком случае можно самому выбрать какой слайдер должен быть активен $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', n); где n это слайдер который мы центрируем

Comment: @Get-Web не совсем понял о чем речь. Мне нужно поведение, что если слайды влезают в экран, то центрировать, и не анимировать прокрутку. Если не влезают, то не надо центрировать и есть прокрутка при смене. вроде такой обычный вид фотогалереи.

Comment: Вы можете сами рассчитать какой элемент должен быть в данный момент центральным и применить к нему после инициализации самого слайдера метод slickGoTo. То есть изначально допустим у нас 3 слайда, но по центру стоит первый. Мы знаем что должен быть второй поэтому применяем к нему $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', n); как именно рассчитывать тут уже зависит от конкретной задачи, адаптивный ли слайдер или нет и т.д..

Comment: вы мне кажется предлагаете писать костыли к библиотеке. я в целом и так в состоянии написать фотогалерею под свои нужны целиком. но я взял готовый продукт, и хочу знать можно ли его заставить работать вполне обыденным для фотогалерии способом. Переписывать основной функционал библиотеки для этого как то странно, не находите? при этом, упомянутые вами goto, надо полагать будут переключать основные слайды, чего мне явно не надо. пока что я тут вижу, что как-то он сомнительно вообще работает с `variableWidth` хоть по центру, хоть и без центра.

Comment: Я библиотеку вообще не предлагаю трогать, вам нужно поставить слайдер по ценрту, для этого есть математика и метод slickGoTo, но если вам проще писать свою либо, то вперед.

Comment: а вы видимо по диагонали читаете. `slickGoTo` делает слайд активным, мне это не нужно, и переключает основной слайдер.  Вы понимаете вообще, что предлагаете мне начать просмотр галереи со второго слайда, чтобы центрировать внешний вид?

Comment: Да, я прекрасно понимаю. По другому centerMode не поставит слайдер по центру. И да я сразу сказал, что нужно сделать активным тот слайд, который хотите центрировать, так работает slick.

Answer (score 1):

Оно (не оч понял ворос :)?

```js
$("#slider").slick({    
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  infinite: false,
  
});
```

```css
#slider {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.slide {     
   margin: 0 4px;
   text-align: center;
}
.middle {
   width: 50%;
   background: red;
   height: 5px;
}

.slide-slide{
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
  float:left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide-slide">2wide</div>
    <div class="slide-slide">3</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide-slide">2wide</div>
    <div class="slide-slide">3</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide-slide">2wide</div>
    <div class="slide-slide">3</div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет. у меня уже есть три слайда, не надо их  было дублировать и оборачивать еще в слайды. под слайдером отмечена середина. сейчас все слайды располагаются справа от нее.